# synchronize local and remote mysql databases using javafx

Tags: java, mysql, synchronization

I have a simple java application that shows a database table's informations. These informations can be updated by a user.
Now the application should access two data bases (the same structure, one on localhost, the other on a server) 
So, please, does any one know how to synchronize these two databases using a java code?
I heard about threads but I don't know how to use them..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of synchronization do you need? Only insert new rows and update old ones from the reference db to target? Or this is a two-way synchronization?

Comment: It is a two-way synchronization between remote and local server

Comment: in that case you need to clearly define requirements for synchronization. First of all - how do you want to resolve conflicts when some row is changed in both databases at one time?

Comment: There is a very complex tool within MySQL - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html, but if your case is simpler you could do some manual inserts or updates from java code.

Comment: Thank you! There is another table called "ClientUpdate" with three fields (idClient, dataUp, dataDown), I think that it would be used to store all the updates about the client, but how I don't really know

Comment: Try to explain how would you do this manually. How would you define that one record is new and another isn't? Is the record modified or not? Is the record deleted?

Comment: You may use something like history tables - http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/07/history-tables.html